# Function for when map is interacted with

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I was wondering if there is an inbuilt function that is called whenever a map box map is interacted with?

I’m wondering this because I want to have an image appear whenever the map is moved.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use one of the MGLMapViewDelegate methods depending on your requirements:

`-mapView:regionWillChangeAnimated:
-mapViewRegionIsChanging:
-mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:`

You can read about their implementation in the MapBox api reference here: [Mapbox api](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/api/maps/5.6.1/Protocols/MGLMapViewDelegate.html#/c:objc(pl)MGLMapViewDelegate(im)mapView:regionDidChangeAnimated:)

Comment: I will try this tomorrow, thank you for your response